# How to publish topics at different rates using while loop?

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to fix the hz for one topic `control` to control of the robot at 30 HZ.

I am using object detection in my work,  the hz of the video's topic `/usb_cam/image_raw` is between 15 and 25.

**Note**: I'd like to using while loop in my work.

When  I run this code, the hz above 100 for `control` topic, it is not 30 as I wanted. I am using the command : `rostopic hz /control` to measure of hz.

How to fix it at 30 hz?

Please help me.

Thanks in advince!

Full the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String, Float32MultiArray, Bool, Float32
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, PointCloud2

class Detector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pubtracking = rospy.Publisher('control', Float32MultiArray, queue_size=1)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 30), self.control)

        self._bridge = CvBridge()
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/usb_cam/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/points', PointCloud2, self.pc_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('stopback', Bool, self.shutdownlistener)
        self._current_image = None
        self._current_pc = None
        # self.array = 0
        self.error_v = 0
        self.error_w = 0


    def image_callback(self, image):
        self._current_image = image
    def run(self):
        global error_v, error_w, array
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            if self._current_image is not None:
                try:
                    scene = self._bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(self._current_image, "bgr8")
                    self.error_v = 2
                    self.error_w = 1
                    # hello_str = [error_v, error_w]
                    # array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
                    self.control()

                    cv2.imshow("image", scene)
                    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                except CvBridgeError as e:
                    print(e)

    def control(self, event=None):
        # error_v = 2
        # error_w = 1
        hello_str = [self.error_v, self.error_w]
        print hello_str
        array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
        self.pubtracking.publish(array)
        # rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 30), self.control)
        # rospy.spin()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('dodo_detector_ros', log_level=rospy.INFO)
    try:
        tr = Detector()
        tr.run()
        # rospy.spin()
        # tr.control()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

I need it works like this code but using while loop, I don't know if it is possible or not in ROS?

Here I put hs = 50

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String, Float32MultiArray, Bool, Float32
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, PointCloud2

class Detector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pubtracking = rospy.Publisher('control', Float32MultiArray, queue_size=1)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 50), self.control)

        self._bridge = CvBridge()
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/usb_cam/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/points', PointCloud2, self.pc_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('stopback', Bool, self.shutdownlistener)
        self._current_image = None
        self._current_pc = None
        # self.array = 0
        self.error_v = 0
        self.error_w = 0


    def image_callback(self, image):
        self._current_image = image
    # def run(self):
        global error_v, error_w, array
        # rate = rospy.Rate(30)
        # while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        if self._current_image is not None:
            try:
                scene = self._bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(self._current_image, "bgr8")
                self.error_v = 2
                self.error_w = 1
                # hello_str = [error_v, error_w]
                # array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
                # rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1), self.control)
                # self.control()

                cv2.imshow("image", scene)
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            except CvBridgeError as e:
                print(e)
        # rate.sleep()

    def control(self, event=None):
        # error_v = 2
        # error_w = 1
        hello_str = [self.error_v, self.error_w]
        print hello_str
        array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
        self.pubtracking.publish(array)
        # rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 30), self.control)
        # rospy.spin()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('dodo_detector_ros', log_level=rospy.INFO)
    try:
        tr = Detector()
        # tr.run()
        rospy.spin()
        # tr.control()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372017/how-to-publish-topics-at-different-rates-using-while-loop?/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works fine now

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String, Float32MultiArray, Bool, Float32
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, PointCloud2

class Detector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pubtracking = rospy.Publisher('control', Float32MultiArray, queue_size=1)
        rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 50), self.control)

        self._bridge = CvBridge()
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("/usb_cam/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('/camera/depth/points', PointCloud2, self.pc_callback)
        # rospy.Subscriber('stopback', Bool, self.shutdownlistener)
        self._current_image = None
        self._current_pc = None
        # self.array = 0
        self.error_v = 0
        self.error_w = 0


    def image_callback(self, image):
        self._current_image = image
    def run(self):
        global error_v, error_w, array
        rate = rospy.Rate(30)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            if self._current_image is not None:
                try:
                    scene = self._bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(self._current_image, "bgr8")
                    self.error_v = 2
                    self.error_w = 1
                    # hello_str = [error_v, error_w]
                    # array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
                    # self.control()

                    cv2.imshow("image", scene)
                    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                    rate.sleep()
                except CvBridgeError as e:
                    print(e)

    def control(self, event=None):
        # error_v = 2
        # error_w = 1
        hello_str = [self.error_v, self.error_w]
        print hello_str
        array = Float32MultiArray(data=hello_str)
        self.pubtracking.publish(array)
        # rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1 / 30), self.control)
        # rospy.spin()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('dodo_detector_ros', log_level=rospy.INFO)
    try:
        tr = Detector()
        tr.run()
        # rospy.spin()
        # tr.control()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

---

Originally posted by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) with karma: 73 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-02-18**:
I'm glad you got it working, but it should be noted that you're no longer using the `while` loop to control the `control` publisher timing; it's being handled by the `rospy.Timer`.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2021-02-18**:
First of all, I'd like to thank you a lot. Your help inspired me to solve it, although I had tried before and gave up.
In fact, I have many rostopic publishers are dependent on hz of while loop, and I had wanted to make only rostopic control will be independent.